# Как узнать ключ по значению в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Имеется массив:
`{MdCf0JQtOS0x: '1ПД-9-1', MdCf0JQtOS0y: '1ПД-9-2', MdCf0JQtOS0z: '1ПД-9-3', MdCf0KHQni05: '1ПСО-9', MdCY0KHQny05LTE: '1ИСП-9-1', …}`

Как зная значение (допустим,  1ПД-9-2') получить ключ (MdCf0JQtOS0y)?

Comment: Вариаций очень много.... Вот ещё такой например `Object.entries(obj).filter(e => e[1] === '1ПД-9-2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = {MdCf0JQtOS0x: '1ПД-9-1', MdCf0JQtOS0y: '1ПД-9-2', MdCf0JQtOS0z: '1ПД-9-3', MdCf0KHQni05: '1ПСО-9', MdCY0KHQny05LTE: '1ИСП-9-1'};

console.log(Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === '1ПД-9-2'));
```